# Как обнулить историю Git?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-remote, git-push

Ситуация такая: на сервере удалил репозиторий и создал заново, с локального теперь нужно сделать `push`, но если сделаю, то всю историю коммитов запишет на сервер.

Как начать с нуля?

Comment: скорее всего просто удалить папку `.git`, но не факт, я просто подумал что это можно сделать консольными `git` - командами.

Comment: я думаю, что удаление .git - самое правильное решение (копию перед этим лучше сделать).

Но можно пойти хитрее - слить все коммиты в один:)

Comment: @KoVadim написал детальные инструкции по вашему предложению.

Answer (score 15):

Все эти инструкции верны, если на удаленном сервере у вас пусто, а локально - есть проект и репозиторий Git с историей, которую вы хотите удалить.

## Что будет потеряно безвозвратно

1. Собственно, история. Вы точно хотите ее потерять? Ради нее весь Git и придумывался.
2. Весь код в не-слитых (unmerged) ветках.
3. Весь код в orphaned ветках.
4. Метки (tags)

## Быстрый способ

Найдите первый коммит в ветке, запомните его sha1.

```
 git log --oneline
```

Переключитесь на тот коммит, который хотите сохранить в итоге.

```
git checkout master
```

Теперь используем `git reset --soft` чтобы сделать из всей истории один коммит (подробнее - пункт 4.1: [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431521/181472) ).

```
git reset --soft <first-commit-sha1>
git commit -m'слил историю в один коммит'
```

## Долгий способ

Сделайте бэкап локального репозитория. Можно запушить на резервный удаленный репозиторий, а можно просто взять и переместить папку `.git` в другое место.

```
mkdir ../git-backup
mv .git ../git-backup/.git
```

Если не переместили локально, а забэкапили куда-то еще: удаляем папку.

```
rm -Rf .git
```

Теперь заново инициализируем репозиторий:

```
git init
```

[Добавляем все файлы в рабочей области](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431840/181472) и делаем коммит.

```
git add .
git commit -m'начал с нуля'
```

## Когда все готово

Подключаем удаленный репозиторий и заливаем на него изменения:

```
git remote add origin <url>
git push -u origin --all
```

Answer (score 2):

Сделать clone, скопировать файлы (без .git), сделать push! Нет? ))

Comment: Нет, придется еще коммит сделать.

Answer (score 2):

**Эта команда делает совсем другое**: стирает всю историю до `commitId` и возвращает рабочую область к его состоянию. **При этом вы потеряете данные более поздних коммитов.**

```
git reset --hard commitId #УДАЛЯЕТ ИСТОРИЮ GIT
```