# Bitbucket удаление репозитория

Tags: git, bitbucket

Добрый день!

На bitbucket удаляю репозиторий, в cmd выполняю:

```
git reset --hard
git remote rm
```

Создаю на bitbucket новый репозиторий с тем же именем.

```
git init 
git remote add origin <repository_https_url_from_bitbucket>
git add README.md
git add .gitignore
git commit -m “init”
git add .
git commit -m “test tasks”
git push -u origin --all
```

и снова на bitbucket все старые коммиты. где ещё я что-то забыл удалить?

Comment: так вы из локальной репы никакие коммиты не удаляете

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Как удалить историю коммитов в репозитории:

#### Локально

- [Как обнулить историю Git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/229431/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8e-git)
- Вопрос не совсем про это, но связанный: [Если нужно удалить Git tracking (версионирование), правильно ли просто удалить папку .git/?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541242/%d0%95%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-git-tracking-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf)

#### На удалённом репозитории

(например, Bitbucket, GitLab, GitHub и т.п.):

Пересоздавать репозиторий в принципе необязательно. Если вы уже обнулили локальную историю, вы можете просто отправить её на удалённый репозиторий с ключом `-f`.

```
git push -f origin
```

**Внимание, это нельзя делать, если репозиторием пользуется ещё кто-то кроме вас! ([подробнее о том, почему так и что за это будет.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/429519/181472))**

При этом будет заменено только содержимое ветки `origin/master`. Если на удалённом репозитории есть другие ветки, их можно удалить следующим образом (отдельно для каждой ветки с именем, например, `branchname`):

```
git push origin :branchname
```

Разумеется, если там много веток и/или тегов, то будет проще удалить и пересоздать весь репозиторий.

## Что произошло, почему остались старые коммиты

Разберём последовательно все выполненные команды.

```
git reset --hard
```

Просто сбросили локальные изменения.

```
git remote rm
```

Не работает без ещё одного аргумента, вы просто не заметили ошибку. Но даже если делать так:

```
git remote rm origin
```

То удалится только запись в конфигурации локального репозитория о подключенном репозитории (remote) под именем `origin`.

Дальше:

```
git init
```

Если эта команда выполняется в уже существующем репозитории, то [она ничего не делает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428172/181472). Если вы хотите удалить историю изменений и начать версионирование с нуля, нужно было идти другим путём: [Как обнулить историю Git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/229431/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8e-git)

```
git remote add origin <repository_https_url_from_bitbucket>
```

Поскольку репозиторий под именем `origin` уже есть в локальной конфигурации, ничего не произойдёт.

```
git add README.md
git add .gitignore
git commit -m “init”
git add .
git commit -m “test tasks”
```

Просто добавили пару коммитов в локальный репозиторий. Если на каком-то шаге изменений не было (были добавлены/индексированы файлы, не содержащие изменений), то и коммита не было.

```
git push -u origin --all
```

И запушили полученный результат на репозиторий `origin`. Закономерно видим там всю ту же историю коммитов, которая есть у нас локально. Посмотреть на локальную можно, например, так:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

---

Comment: А если он теги успел залить, ох, замучается удалять вручную, если их больше 10.

Comment: @0andriy дополнил чуть ответ. Но я слабо себе представляю ситуацию, когда в репозитории уже есть много веток или тем более тегов и вдруг нужно начать историю с нуля. Тегами обычно что-то ценное обозначается вроде релизов, зачем бы их терять.